# VBA Saving CSV (comma delimited)

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I can Save worksheets manually as CSV (Comma delimited) with UTF-8 Encoding, without any errors.
However when I use the below code to do it, the resulting CSV has a `#NAME?` error in 2 of the cells.

In these 2 cells is a formula for a User Defined "TEXT JOIN" function. I could post that (long) code here, but given that when I save manually the cells in question display correctly I figure there is something missing in my code that makes it differ from a manual save.

```
Sub SheetsToCSV()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xcsvFile As String
    Dim SaveToDirectory As String
    SaveToDirectory = "Z:\CSV\"
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            xWs.Copy
            xcsvFile = SaveToDirectory & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv"
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xcsvFile, _
            FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

What could the issue be?

Comment: The Copy step creates a new workbook without your UDF, hence the #NAME

Comment: Try using `FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8`. If Excel version is newer than 2016 (inclusive)...

Comment: @FaneDuru error 1004 Save AS of Object Failed on these 2 lines ```Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xcsvFile,``` ```FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8, CreateBackup:=False```

Comment: What Excel version do you use?

Comment: 2007..................

Comment: So, read what I said in my comment when I recommended that solution...

Comment: Ah yes, but I had already tried it before you edited your comment.

Comment: @TimWilliams Im wondering what it is about a UDF vs an inbuilt one that makes the resulting value stick when using COPY. Is there another way to go about it?

Comment: I thought I was fast enough... I remembered something about your Excel version and I was not sure that I am not wrong.

Comment: COPY may be the issue. This is in order to not override the open file. Are there any other ways?

Comment: Please, try using `FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText`, but keep the `.csv` extension.

Comment: CSV is not an excel file, it's a text file. What do you see if you open the CSV in a text editor?

Comment: @FaneDuru I commented 2 lines and added this ```Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xcsvFile, _``` ```FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText, CreateBackup:=False```. #NAME? error still occurring.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Opened in Notepad and output is the same, still contains error.

Comment: Please, test the code I posted and send some feedback.

Comment: @FaneDuru I have sent the file

Comment: I am afraid that I only now I could understand your problem... Calling  a UDF function in a formula, in order to make it returning something, the UDF function must exist in the workbook where it is called. But copying only a sheet like a (intermediary) workbook, the necessary function does not exist...

Comment: Now, after understanding of what is it about, I do not think that I need the file in discussion. Do you still need the function in the workbook where from you export sheets?

Comment: I do understand what you are saying. But if it is a manual Save AS CSV, and then the file is closed and reopened, the reopened file contains nothing, no vba, no functions, but still displays the results correctly.

Comment: I need the function to turn many cells of data into a comma separated string. The length is always changing so Concatenate wouldn't be appropriate. I still think there is something else going on here, as formulas are not stored in the CSV either. It is the way in which the file is COPIED or some other thing that I do not understand.

Comment: When you manually save it, you do not copy the sheet and then it is saved as a different workbook, not having the  necessary reference. You simply saveAs the active sheet, **in the same workbook** where the UDF function exist. I will try finding a solution, but different of what I have in mind when misunderstood the question.

Comment: Please, test the your updated code I pasted. Not tested in 2007, but your problem should be independent of Excel version. This version adds a new workbook (having a single worksheet) and use it as buffer/helper to paste only values in it, and save as CSV after. I do not know if your code as it is really saves UDF-8 encoded... But this is another issue, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. In order to avoid the missing UDF issue, in the intermediary workbook to be saved, it uses a helper workbook where only the values are pasted:

```
Sub SheetsToCSVNew()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet, xcsvFile As String, wbAct As Workbook, wbHelp As Workbook
    Dim wsH As Worksheet, SaveToDirectory As String, arrCopy
    
    Set wbAct = ActiveWorkbook  'set the active workbook
    Set wbHelp = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) 'add a new workbook
    Set wsH = wbHelp.Sheets(1)  'set the new workbook first sheet
    
    SaveToDirectory = "Z:\CSV\"
    For Each xWs In wbAct.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            arrCopy = xWs.UsedRange.Value 'put the sheet content in an array
            With wsH
                .Cells.ClearContents      'clear the helper sheet before a new pasting - saving as step
                .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrCopy), UBound(arrCopy, 2)).Value = arrCopy                       'drop the array content at once
                .UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit 'Fit the columns in the pasted sheet
            End With
            xcsvFile = SaveToDirectory & xWs.Name & ".csv"
            wbHelp.SaveAs Filename:=xcsvFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV
        End If
    Next
    wbHelp.Close False 'close the helper workbook
End Sub
```

Comment: @aye cee Do you want putting a formula **in a CSV file**?

Comment: No, the original file, contains 2 cells that use a user defined function in the formula. It is a TEXTJOIN function as 2007 doesn't have this. I then save the sheets as CSV. If I save manually, the result of the formula (words separated by commas) are shown correctly. If CSV are created with this vba code those 2 cells show the output as ```#NAME``` instead.

Comment: As Tim commented, it could be COPY is the problem.

Comment: So there is no confusion, around this answer, if you want to delete all above comments relating to the previous answer then I can too.

Comment: Deleted everything related to the first answer code... But, are you sure that your code (the adapted one, too) is able to deal with UTF-8? Don't you use special characters which to require such a type? In my previous answer I was focused only on this aspect. Now I did not check anything, from this point of view... When required this, did you imagine that it will solve your problem, in fact related to the UDF function reference missing?